# How does this C code work? The ptr assignment is unclear

Tags: c, pointers, casting, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
   char *ptr =(char*)(&a+1);
   printf("%d %d \n",*(a+1),*(ptr-1));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is: 2 7

I'm unable to find out how the outcome came to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays used in expressions are implicitly converted to pointers to their firs elements.

So in this expression `*(a+1)` the array designator `a` is converted to pointer of the type `char *` to its first element and the expression `a + 1` points to the second element of the array. Dereferencing the pointer expression `(a+1)` like `*(a+1)` you get the second element of the array, Actually the expression *(a+1) is the same as the expression `a[1]`.

This expression `&a`  has the pointer type `char ( * )[7]` that points to the whole array a of the type `char[7]`.

This expression `(&a+1)` points to the memory after the last element of the array and has the same type `char ( * )[7]`. This pointer expression is casted to the type `char *`.

```
char *ptr =(char*)(&a+1);
```

So the pointer p points to the memory after the last element of the array a.

The expression `ptr-1` points to the last element of the array and dereferencing this expression like `*(ptr-1)` you get the last element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

`(char*)(&a+1)`:

1. `&a` is giving the pointer to array of 7 `char` elements (type `char (*)[7]`)
2. `+1` is giving the reference of the first element of the **next** 7 `char` elements array (which is beyond your array)
3. `(char *)` casts it to the pointer to `char`.
4. `ptr-1` is referencing the last element of the `a` array (as ptr is referencing the object one `char` past the end of the `a` array